# Django: How to create an admin 'list of Calculations' in admin, for example BMI, Body Surface, Age

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to design the possibility to make a large number of calculations in a Django Project. The data are provided by patients, such as weight, length, Date of birth. I would like to create in Django admin a list with calculations for each parameter. That way I can easily adjust and expand with Body Surface Area, Ideal Bodyweight, and make calculations for kids, women, and men, for kg/com and pd/inch, etc. Could anybody give me an example of how to do this? I would like python used for the calculations in the admin listed calculations.
Thanks, Hans

Comment: Is that list of calculation **dynamic** (changeable by admins at run-time) or just a bunch of _fixed_ formulas that you want to apply to each persons's data?

Answer (score 0):

In the PatientAdmin, you can define custom values for the list view of Patients.

```
class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'id', 'get_bmi')

    def get_bmi(self, instance):
        return instance.calculate_bmi()

    get_bmi.short_description = 'BMI'
    # get_bmi.boolean = True  # for bool values
```